# unable to run mysql from terminal | command not found

Tags: mysql, bash, path

```
echo $PATH  
/usr/local/mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-osx10.7-x86_64/bin
```

PATH looks correct to me, What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What does `ls /usr/local/mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysql` print? If it doesn't find the file it can't be executed (obviously).

Comment: yeah that doesn't find the file, however "ls /usr/local/mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-osx10.7-x86_64/include/mysql" this lists some files. I tried changing PATH to include but that doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the `mysql` executable? If you don't have an executable this is never going to work. You need to have installed or compiled MySQL for this to work.